# Bootstrap Image Sizing and Centering

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image-size

I am new to bootstrap and I am having an issue trying to position an Image on the page.  I am trying to use bootstrap grid to position the image in the center of the page.  I am familiar with html5 and **I know there are other ways of centering the image**;however,I was wondering if this can be done using bootstrap's grid system.  The reason for this example, is that I have other image position things I would like to use bootstrap for.

When I run the example below on a Windows 8 desktop or iPad the image is extremely small(i.e. almost like an icon) and resides in the upper left corner; however, when I run this on my Nexus 5 the image is sized correctly and is centered. I have included some sample html code of what I am using.

Again, I am some what new to bootstrap so it could be something simple.  Any input or advice is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Autoroute Login</title>   
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
 height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
       3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/
         css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<style>
  @media (min-width:@screen-sm-min){
    #main-image{
        height: 200px;
      width:200px;
        }        
  }

  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min){
    #main-image{
        height: 350px;
         width: 350px;
        }
  }

</style>

</head>  
<body>

  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"/>
     <div id="main-image" class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
       <img src="img/ar-main-image.jpg" alt="Autoroute Main Image"
         class="img-responsive center-block"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"/>
     </div>    
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/
           jquery.min.js" >   </script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/
          bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's column system is laid out on a base of twelve. For example, if you wanted two columns of equal width,  you would have them both be `.col-sm-6` because two columns with widths of 6 equals twelve. Likewise, you could have three equal `.col-md-4` columns.

Bootstrap floats columns to the left by default, but also allows you to offset them by a specific number of columns: `.col-md-offset-4`

So, if you would like to have a Bootstrap div that is always centered, you can do that by setting it's width to any even number, subtracting that number from 12, and setting the offset to that number. So for a centered .col-2, you would give an offset of 5 because 5+5+2=12. For a centered .col-4, you would give an offset of 4 because 4+4+4=12. You need to account for the left (empty) columns, the center div with x columns width, and the right (empty) columns.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5531/)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think this will resolve the centering issue; however, I was wondering if you know why the image on my desktop and iPad is displayed very small (i.e. like an icon), where as on my Nexus 5 the image is displayed properly.  I have specified the media definitions at the top of the page, but it does not seem to be working.